# CSS max-height with inherit

Tags: css, css-selectors

The CSS reference explicitly says that `max-height` is not inherited. Problem is, I want it to be inherited. However, I can't seem to get the correct CSS incantation. Thing is, I have a CSS class that I'd like to apply to DIVs and then enforce that all children of said DIV honor the `max-height` property:

```
.my-viewer {
  max-height: 800px;
}

* {
  max-height: inherit;
}
```

Unfortunately, the above code does not work. In the Chrome development tools, for example, the 'inherit' setting of `max-height' is crossed out, as disabled. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding but shouldn't this work?

```
.my-viewer {
  max-height: 800px;
}

.my-viewer * {
  max-height: inherit;
}
```

That would be all children elements of `.my-viewer`. If that doesn't work, what should work is `max-height:100%` as they are children of `.my-viewer`. And I'm assuming only `.my-viewer divs` are what you want to inherit, not all elements such as `a` `p` and so on.

```
.my-viewer {
  max-height: 800px;
}

.my-viewer div {
  position:relative;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

EDIT: If you're looking to be more specific use the `>` selector.

`.my-viewer > *` or `.my-viewer > div`

Comment: That would be all children of `.my-viewer` and all their children and all their grandchildren and all their great^n grandchildren :P

Comment: Well, he didn't really clarify only direct children but if need be he can change it to be more specific. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: "children" does imply a direct parent-child relationship, but I'm just being an annoying pedant so I'll stop.

Comment: descendants...and css can be so annoying

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a different css selector:

```
.my-viewer {
  max-height: 800px;
}
.my-viewer * {
  max-height: inherit;
}
```

But note, that this will not work in IE anyway (or at least before IE 8), See [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=minmaxwh)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
* {   max-height: inherit; }

.my-viewer {   max-height: 800px; }
```